# What bedroom would the simulator room closet door lead to when activated?

Tags: monsters-inc

OK, so, when Sulley traps Waternoose out the simulator room, he takes the simulator room closet door of the control panels. Earlier in the film, we see Waternoose send said door to the door station.

My question is: If activated, where would it lead? Or is the red light broken, like Sulley did to the door they banished Randall through? Or is it a door simply made for the simulator room and it CAN’T be activated?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since "*dead*" doors are immediately and instantly shredded as a potential hazard and "*live*" doors are an increasingly scarce and valuable resource, it stands to reason that the door to the simulator rooms is, in all likelihood, just a dummy.

> **Jerry:** *We've lost 58 doors this week, Sir.*
>
> **Waternoose:** *Oh, kids these day. They just don't get scared like they used to.*

We see the students of MU making doors by the dozen before they're taken to be tested in the laboratory next door. It's not clear at what point the doors are 'activated' (linked to real-world doors) but hand-painting an *unfinished door* would create much the desired effect for a simulated door.

[image]